# In the app store how do you determine if an app is iCloud compatible before purchase?

Tags: applications, icloud, ios-appstore, games

A few months ago on the [Arqade](http://arqade.stackexchange.com) site I asked if [the iOS version of Chrono Trigger put save games in the cloud](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/107378/559). DCol provided a great answer detailing how to [check if iOS apps you own backup to the cloud](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/114434/559):

> To check for other games/apps (if you own them) look under Settings >
>   iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage.
>
> The apps listed under 'Documents & Data' sync between devices.
>
> The apps listed under your device's name are backed up, but not synced
>   via iCloud unless they are also in the previously mentioned list.
>
> Some games/apps sync using cloud servers other than iCloud (Eg:
>   Dropbox). In this case, they would appear in the back-up list, but not
>   the Documents & Data list, but would still be syncing.

While his answer is still the best one given the question I asked I was about to ask a similar question concerning another game. Obviously this won't scale. Is there a way in the app store to determine if an app (game) is iCloud (or other sync service) compatible before purchase?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly the best option is to just read the description in the App Store, the developer's website, and any reviews you can find. There's nothing in the App Store metadata that will tell you whether it uses iCloud or not.